# Already save has_many relation in getCMSField_forpopup records in appearing again in every new records in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I have one getCMSField_forpopup form for an event. I made another popup inside that to give multiple dates to that event(using has_many relation). When I give date 2 different dates/times to event "A" and then after saving event "A", I open main getCMSField_forpopup to enter details of another event "B" then I see dates/times (complextablefield) already there which were actually meant to appear in event A's detail not in event "B". I want to see those only with A not with every new event. How can I make that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you enter Dates for 1 Event, but then you can see this Dates on every single Event?

to me this sounds like either your Event has no ID at this time and therefore a query on Dates "WHERE EventID = x" does not work, or your Dates get saved without the ID of the Event

You could simply check your database if your Dates have the ID of an Event set.

1. If the ID if the Event is 0, then the issue is that you are not saving the event ID, this either means that:

   - you have created the Dates before saving the Event, in this case the solution is just saving the Event before you add Dates, you could also hide the Dates field when it has not been saved, see below the $this->isNew() stuff
   - or silverstripe fails to save the EventID, in this case you could fix it by adding a hidden field to your getCMSFields_forPopup of the Date and save the Event ID there, but its gonna be a little tricky getting this ID into the popup
2. if this is not the issue, then the problem is that when you create a new Event it has no ID, and therefore can not filter by ID, you can simply do this inside your getCMSFields_forPopup of the Event:

   ```
   if (!$this->isNew()) {
      // add your ComplexTableField for Dates here so it only 
      // gets added if this record has already been saved
   }
   ```

**But actually I would recommend using nested DataObjectManager (a DataObjectManager inside a DataObjectManager)(see tutorial on youtube: http://youtu.be/eeXOTlXFmQQ), DataObjectManager does all that work for you, so this problem should not occur.

It only displays the DataObjectManager for Dates if you have already saved the Event once, otherwise it tells the user that he needs to save it first.
And it also sets the Event ID on the Dates for you**

Or, even better, you could upgrade to SilverStripe 3, where you can use GridField.
GridField works way better then DataObjectManager and looks a lot nicer.